# Filtering ObservableCollection with ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have `ObservableCollection` binded to `dataGrid` and now I want to filter the presented data I see that I need to use `ICollectionView` but I am not sure how to add `ICollectionView` with my `MVVM` pattern.

My code simplified looks following:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase , IBarcodeHandler
{
    public ObservableCollection<TraceDataItem> TraceItemCollectionViewSource { get; set; }
}
```

My XAML

```
    <Window xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Mentor.Valor.vManage.RepairStation.Controls"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ColumnWidth="*"  ItemsSource="{Binding TraceItemCollectionViewSource , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" RowStyle="{StaticResource TraceRowStyle}"  IsReadOnly="True" Name="TraceDataGrid" Margin="5,5,5,5" Padding="5,5,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    </Window>
```

How I can add `ICollectionView` here in order to apply filtering to the view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IBarcodeHandler
{
    public ICollectionView TraceItemCollectionView
    {
        get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TraceItemCollectionViewSource); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TraceDataItem> TraceItemCollectionViewSource { get; set; }
}
```

then, somewhere in the code (maybe in the constructor) add your filter:

```
TraceItemCollectionView.Filter = o =>
{
    var item = (TraceDataItem) o;

    //based on item, return true if it should be visible, or false if not

    return true;
};
```

And, in XAML, you would need to change the binding to TraceItemCollectionView property.

Comment: so every time I change TraceItemCollectionViewSource I need to RaisePropertyChanged on TraceItemCollectionView to notify the UI ?

Comment: @NightWalker Yes you do. However, the entire point of an ObservableCollection is that you don't need to change it.

Comment: @Andrew If using the default view of the collection, there is no need to change the xaml binding. Binding to the collection directly is the same as binding to the default view (ItemsControl always binds to the default view when binding to a collection).

Comment: @Xavier Correct. I was actually thinking that TraceItemCollectionViewSource should be a private readonly field and not be exposed anymore.

Comment: How would you update the `get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TraceItemCollectionViewSource); }` when refreshing data from a database?

Answer (score 1):

You may invoke the Filter callback from a Command and expose the View property from CollectionViewSource :

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CollectionViewSource data = new CollectionViewSource();
    private ObservableCollection<Child> observableChilds = new ObservableCollection<Child>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var model = new Model();
        model.ChildList.Add(new Child { Name = "Child 1" });
        model.ChildList.Add(new Child { Name = "Child 2" });
        model.ChildList.Add(new Child { Name = "Child 3" });
        model.ChildList.Add(new Child { Name = "Child 4" });
        //Populate ObservableCollection
        model.ChildList.ToList().ForEach(child => observableChilds.Add(child));

        this.data.Source = observableChilds;
        ApplyFilterCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnApplyFilterCommand);
    }

    public ICollectionView ChildCollection
    {
        get { return data.View; }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ApplyFilterCommand { get; set; }

    private void OnApplyFilterCommand()
    {
        data.View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(x => ((Child)x).Name == "Child 1");
        OnPropertyChanged("ChildCollection");
    }
}

//Sample Model used
public class Model
{
    public Model() 
    {
        ChildList = new HashSet<Child>();
    }

    public ICollection<Child> ChildList { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//View
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path = ChildCollection}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Button Command="{Binding ApplyFilterCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CollectionView` is not always the best solution. you can also filter your collection using some simple LinQ. Take this simple example:

```
public ObservableCollection<TraceDataItem> FilteredData
{
    get 
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<TraceDataItem>(YourUnfilteredCollection.Where(
            i => MeetsFilterRequirements(i))); 
    }
}

private bool MeetsFilterRequirements(TraceDataItem item)
{
    return item.SomeProperty == someValue || item is SomeType;
}
```

The beauty of this method is that you can add some complex filtering requirements. One thing to note: whenever any properties in this method are changed, you'd need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("FilteredData")` to ensure that the UI will be updated accordingly.

Comment: This will cause a compile time Exception. "Where" returns an IEnumerable not a collection.

Comment: Not a good edit in my opinion.  You are better off returning an IEnumerable.   If you are newing each time what is the purpose to an ObservableCollection?